# Upload database backup from mysql to Amazon S3 or Glacier without creating local file

Tags: mysql, backup, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a tool that makes possible to backup a Mysql database to Amazon S3 or Amazon Glacier without having o create a local file with the database contents?

Something like that:

> mysqldump -u root -ppass -h host --all-databases | magical-s3-tool s3-bucket backup-yyyy-mm-dd.sql

This magical tool would use the pipe data and transfer the backup data directly to S3, without creating a local file.

EDIT:

My goal is to avoid having to use a VM with a huge disk for running the backup process.

Comment: You could probably stream it into an S3FS mountpoint.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the creation of a file?  The answer to this might help frame the recommended approach.

Comment: I am not sure about S3 but you can often pipe over SSH like this:

mysqldump  | ssh remote-box "cat > file.sql"

Comment: @Eric Hammond yes, i'm trying to avoid the creation of a file

Comment: @RubemAzenha: Yes, that's clear... but why?  (performance, security, regulations, size, disk space, for the fun of it, ...?)  If you can explain what your underlying goals are, that can lead to a better answer that meets those goals.  You can simply update the question above with your criteria, philosophies, and driving constraints.

Comment: I want to save Disk space. I want to avoid having to use a VM with a huge disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
mysqldump \
    --host=127.0.0.1 --port=1234 \
    --user='username' --password='password' \
    --single-transaction --routines --triggers --compress --compact \
    --databases '<database name>' | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://'<bucket name>'/'<database name>'.sql.gz
```

Comment: thanks... Do you know how do the same thing with mydumper? I know it would be harder since mydumper has multiple files.

Comment: I'd recommend using the default AWS CLI.. What is the use case of `mydumper` anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool https://github.com/vsespb/mt-aws-glacier which can do this (Amazon Glacier only). See `--stdin` option in documentation.

Note that this operation will block your mysqldump (if network is bottleneck), and this can cause problems with mysql lockings etc.